# Sorting dictionary keys without using Lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

How can I sort dictionary keys by value, then those with the same value alphabetically?

I have a dictionary of names and averages, what is the basic function to use instead of:

```py
sorted_name_averages=sorted(name_averages.items(), key=lambda t: t[::-1])
```

Comment: Can you include your dictionary or atleast a part of it, so it would be easier for us to try it out.

Comment: Please add more tags, to make the question reach to right people. Add `python3.x`, `python`. Also, check out the answer, and let me know if that works for you :)

Answer (score 2):

Let your dictionary be:

```
dic={'c':1,'b':2,'a':3}
dic2={}
for key in sorted(dic.keys()) :
    dic2[key]={dic[key]}
print(dic2)
```

This will return the following result result:

```
{'a':{3},'b':{2},'c':{1}}
```

**Note:** If you try to give duplicate key values, they get updated. there can be no two keys with the same name.

Hope this helped!
If not, sorry for wasting your time. I could not find a better option.    :)

Answer (score 1):

To understand your problem better, I am pointing down the use case, these are:

- You want to sort the dictionary based upon the average
- If the value matches, we can sort it alphabetically
- No use of `Lamba`

So, keeping your use case in mind, we will be writing down the algorithm, which is not very efficient, but will do the job, which you want. The algo goes like this:

> 1. Create a new student date dictionary to store all the person who has same average
> 2. Sort the new dictionary and store it in the same dictionary itself
> 3. Create a new dictionary again, now store the final result
> 4. Traverse through the student date dictionary
>
>    - Sort the list which contains multiple person having same values
>    - Iterate through the values again
>    - Store the Key, value pair accordingly in the new_dictionary
> 5. Print the result

I have seen your code, and this works fine, however, the solution which you are about to see is, kinda long. `Complexity: O(n^3)`

```
# Taking dummy dictionary into consideration for the test
student_average = {'Harsh': 50, 'Raghav': 70, 'Harshit': 50, 'Saurav': 90, 'Akash': 70, 'Bob': 60}

# This contains the list of people having same average
new_student_data = {}

# Storing the data in to the new dictionary
for key, value in student_average.items():
    if value not in student_data:
        student_data[value] = [key]
    else:
        student_data[value].append(key)

# Sorting the same dictionary and storing       
student_data = dict(sorted(student_data.items()))

print(student_data) # OUTPUT => {50: ['Harsh', 'Harshit'], 60: ['Bob'], 70: ['Raghav', 'Akash'], 90: ['Saurav']}

# Final dictionary to store the result as per our requirements
result = {}

for key, value in student_data.items():
    value.sort() # sorting the list so that, we have alphabetically ordered data
    for item in value: # Iterating through the sorted list now
        result[item] = key # using value item as key, and KEY as value in the new dict

print(result)

# OUTPUT
# >>> {'Harsh': 50, 'Harshit': 50, 'Bob': 60, 'Akash': 70, 'Raghav': 70, 'Saurav': 90}
```

I hope this will resolve what you are looking for in a more broader way. Let me know if that helps you out in any way :)